# ASP.Net C# MCV - Pass value from Ajax Jquery to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need to pass a value from the front end to the controller, I'm struggling to get it to pass the value.

Ajax/Jquery

```
//unlock user account
    $("#results").on('click', ".unlockactionbutton", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userid = this.getAttribute("userid");
        if (envdd.children(':selected').val() == "") {
            alert("Please select User"); 
        } else {
            alert(userid);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("UnlockUser", "Home", new { userid = userid })",
                //Url.Action("UnlockUser", "Home", new { id = userid });
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(userid),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('error');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is the ActionResult. I've got the code simply putting a comment in the console so I can see that it's worked for now.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UnlockUser(string userid)
    {
        if (userid != "")
        {
            return Json("success - call from HomeController", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your url should be `@Url.Action("UnlockUser", "Home")` and then do `data: { userid : userid }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller action is decorated with `HttpPost` but you're sending a GET request in the `ajax`, change the type to `type: 'POST',`.

You don't need to append data to your query string when issuing a POST request.

Also, if you're specifying `application/json` make sure you send `json`, at the moment you're sending a string. So, you could either remove the line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` or change the data parameter to `data: JSON.stringify({ userid: userid })`.

Your `ajax` request could look like:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("UnlockUser", "Home")",  
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(userid),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('error');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Or

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("UnlockUser", "Home")",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "userid" : userid }),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('error');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, your first option helped! Makes sense now!

Answer (score 4):

On your ajax request you are using the verb GET and your action is a POST method.

Comment: Been trying various different ways of achieving this so left over from another attempt! Silly me

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, this will work:

```
$("#results").click(function (){
    var userid = this.getAttribute("userid");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/UnlockUser",
        "data": "{userid:'" + userid + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```